# Error in generated code with protoc-gen-grpc-gateway

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go, grpc-gateway

I'm new to Protocol Buffers and gRPC stuff. Now I'm trying to build a client/server architecture with grpc + grpc-gateway in Go.

I tried to follow some examples but I always end up with the same problem.
After generating the code with `protoc` i run `go build` and I get this error:

```
proto/helloworld/hello_world.pb.gw.go:64:2: cannot use msg (type *HelloReply) as type protoreflect.ProtoMessage in return argument:
        *HelloReply does not implement protoreflect.ProtoMessage (missing ProtoReflect method)
proto/helloworld/hello_world.pb.gw.go:98:2: cannot use msg (type *HelloReply) as type protoreflect.ProtoMessage in return argument:
        *HelloReply does not implement protoreflect.ProtoMessage (missing ProtoReflect method)
```

This is `go.mod`:

```
module github.com/riccardopedrielli/grpc-gateway-test

go 1.15

require (
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.3
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2 v2.2.0
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20210207032614-bba0dbe2a9ea
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.35.0
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.25.0
)
```

This is `hello_world.proto`:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package helloworld;

import "google/api/annotations.proto";

option go_package = "github.com/riccardopedrielli/grpc-gateway-test/proto/helloworld";

// Here is the overall greeting service definition where we define all our endpoints
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/v1/example/echo/{name}"
    };
  }
}

// The request message containing the user's name
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

This is the link to the repository: https://github.com/riccardopedrielli/grpc-gateway-test

A difference I see between the generated go files is that they are importing different protobuf libraries.
The one generated by `protoc-gen-go` imports `github.com/golang/protobuf/proto`.
The one generated by `protoc-gen-grpc-gateway` imports `google.golang.org/protobuf/proto`.
Could this be the cause of the problem?

Still it's not clear to me which one should be used and how to force the same in both the generators.

I'm new to grpc and quite lost at this point, so I could have omitted some important informations. Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you are not the only one encountering [this issue](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/issues/1959). Perhaps try `github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2@v2.1.0` (2.2.0 was only released yesterday).

Comment: I tried `2.1.0`, `2.0.1` and `2.0.0` but nothing changes

Comment: Please post the code generated by protoc. Are you sure *HelloReply has the ProtoReflect method?

Comment: The code generated by protoc is here: https://github.com/riccardopedrielli/grpc-gateway-test/tree/main/proto/helloworld
HelloReply doesn't have ProtoReflect method, that's why grpc-gateway is complaining I think. What I don't know is how to make protoc generate the correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved the issue.

I had installed `protoc` via snap and the stable channel had version `3.11.4`

Now I upgraded to `3.14.0` and everything is working well.

Answer (score 0):

For generating the stubs, we can use either `protoc` or `buf`. `protoc` is the more classic generation experience used widely in the industry. Still, it has a pretty steep learning curve. `buf` is a newer tool built with user experience and speed in mind. It also offers linting and breaking change detection, and something `protoc` doesn’t provide.

You should check out the tutorial series on gRPC-Gateway, i.e., https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/tutorials/. Also, you can refer to my simple hello world program, which uses gRPC-Gateway, i.e., https://github.com/iamrajiv/helloworld-grpc-gateway.